# why this function does not load a page into a div? (jQuery AJAX)

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
//src="jquery.pagination/jquery.pagination2.js"
/**
 * This jQuery plugin displays pagination links inside the selected elements.
 * 
 * This plugin needs at least jQuery 1.4.2
 *
 * @author Gabriel Birke (birke *at* d-scribe *dot* de)
 * @version 2.0rc
 * @param {int} maxentries Number of entries to paginate
 * @param {Object} opts Several options (see README for documentation)
 * @return {Object} jQuery Object
 */
 (function($){
    /**
     * @class Class for calculating pagination values
     */
    $.PaginationCalculator = function(maxentries, opts) {
        this.maxentries = maxentries;
        this.opts = opts;
    }
    
    $.extend($.PaginationCalculator.prototype, {
        /**
         * Calculate the maximum number of pages
         * @method
         * @returns {Number}
         */
        numPages:function() {
            return Math.ceil(this.maxentries/this.opts.items_per_page);
        },
        /**
         * Calculate start and end point of pagination links depending on 
         * current_page and num_display_entries.
         * @returns {Array}
         */
        getInterval:function(current_page)  {
            var ne_half = Math.ceil(this.opts.num_display_entries/2);
            var np = this.numPages();
            var upper_limit = np - this.opts.num_display_entries;
            var start = current_page > ne_half ? Math.max( Math.min(current_page - ne_half, upper_limit), 0 ) : 0;
            var end = current_page > ne_half?Math.min(current_page+ne_half, np):Math.min(this.opts.num_display_entries, np);
            return {start:start, end:end};
        }
    });
    
    // Initialize jQuery object container for pagination renderers
    $.PaginationRenderers = {}
    
    /**
     * @class Default renderer for rendering pagination links
     */
    $.PaginationRenderers.defaultRenderer = function(maxentries, opts) {
        this.maxentries = maxentries;
        this.opts = opts;
        this.pc = new $.PaginationCalculator(maxentries, opts);
    }
    $.extend($.PaginationRenderers.defaultRenderer.prototype, {
        /**
         * Helper function for generating a single link (or a span tag if it's the current page)
         * @param {Number} page_id The page id for the new item
         * @param {Number} current_page 
         * @param {Object} appendopts Options for the new item: text and classes
         * @returns {jQuery} jQuery object containing the link
         */
        createLink:function(page_id, current_page, appendopts){
            var lnk, np = this.pc.numPages();
            page_id = page_id<0?0:(page_id<np?page_id:np-1); // Normalize page id to sane value
            appendopts = $.extend({text:page_id+1, classes:""}, appendopts||{});
            
            
            if(page_id == current_page){
                lnk = $("<span class='current'>" + tab_labels[page_id].label + "</span>");
            }
            else if (appendopts.text == this.opts.next_text || appendopts.text == this.opts.prev_text)
            {
    
                    
                lnk = $("<a>" + tab_labels[page_id].label + "</a>")
                    
                    .attr('href', this.opts.link_to.replace(/__id__/,page_id));
       
            }
            else 
            {
    
                lnk = $("<a>" + tab_labels[page_id].label + "</a>")
                    .attr('href', this.opts.link_to.replace(/__id__/,page_id));
            }
            if(appendopts.classes){ lnk.addClass(appendopts.classes); }
            lnk.data('page_id', page_id);
            return lnk;
            
            
            
            
            
            
        },
        // Generate a range of numeric links 
        appendRange:function(container, current_page, start, end) {
            var i;
            for(i=start; i<end; i++) {
                this.createLink(i, current_page).appendTo(container);
            }
        },
        getLinks:function(current_page, eventHandler) {
            var begin, end,
                interval = this.pc.getInterval(current_page),
                np = this.pc.numPages(),
                fragment = $("<div class='pagination' ></div>");
            
            // Generate "Previous"-Link
            if(this.opts.prev_text && (current_page > 0 || this.opts.prev_show_always)){
                fragment.append(this.createLink(current_page-1, current_page, {text:this.opts.prev_text, classes:"prev"}));
            }
            // Generate starting points
            if (interval.start > 0 && this.opts.num_edge_entries > 0)
            {
                end = Math.min(this.opts.num_edge_entries, interval.start);
                this.appendRange(fragment, current_page, 0, end);
                if(this.opts.num_edge_entries < interval.start && this.opts.ellipse_text)
                {
                    jQuery("<span>"+this.opts.ellipse_text+"</span>").appendTo(fragment);
                }
            }
            // Generate interval links
            this.appendRange(fragment, current_page, interval.start, interval.end);
            // Generate ending points
            if (interval.end < np && this.opts.num_edge_entries > 0)
            {
                if(np-this.opts.num_edge_entries > interval.end && this.opts.ellipse_text)
                {
                    jQuery("<span>"+this.opts.ellipse_text+"</span>").appendTo(fragment);
                }
                begin = Math.max(np-this.opts.num_edge_entries, interval.end);
                this.appendRange(fragment, current_page, begin, np);
                
            }
            // Generate "Next"-Link
            if(this.opts.next_text && (current_page < np-1 || this.opts.next_show_always)){
                fragment.append(this.createLink(current_page+1, current_page, {text:this.opts.next_text, classes:"next"}));
            }
            $('a', fragment).click(eventHandler);
            return fragment;
        }
    });
    
    // Extend jQuery
    $.fn.pagination = function(maxentries, opts){
        
    // Initialize options with default values
    opts = jQuery.extend({
        items_per_page:10,
        num_display_entries:10,
        current_page:0,
        num_edge_entries:0,
        link_to:"#",
        prev_text:"",
        next_text:"",
        ellipse_text:"...",
        prev_show_always:false,
        next_show_always:false,
        renderer:"defaultRenderer",
        callback:function(){return false;}
    },opts||{});
    
    var containers = this,
        renderer, links, current_page;
    
        
        /**
         * This is the event handling function for the pagination links. 
         * @param {int} page_id The new page number
         */
        function pageSelected(evt){
            var links, current_page = $(evt.target).data('page_id');
            containers.data('current_page', current_page);
            links = renderer.getLinks(current_page, pageSelected);
            containers.empty();
            links.appendTo(containers);
            var continuePropagation = opts.callback(current_page, containers);
            if (!continuePropagation) {
                if (evt.stopPropagation) {
                    evt.stopPropagation();
                }
                else {
                    evt.cancelBubble = true;
                }
            }
            return continuePropagation;
        }
        
        current_page = opts.current_page;
        containers.data('current_page', current_page);
        // Create a sane value for maxentries and items_per_page
        maxentries = (!maxentries || maxentries < 0)?1:maxentries;
        opts.items_per_page = (!opts.items_per_page || opts.items_per_page < 0)?1:opts.items_per_page;
        
        if(!$.PaginationRenderers[opts.renderer])
        {
            throw new ReferenceError("Pagination renderer '" + opts.renderer + "' was not found in jQuery.PaginationRenderers object.");
        }
        renderer = new $.PaginationRenderers[opts.renderer](maxentries, opts);
        
        containers.each(function() {
        // Attach control functions to the DOM element 
        this.selectPage = function(page_id){ pageSelected(page_id);}
        this.prevPage = function(){
            var current_page = containers.data('current_page');
            if (current_page > 0) {
                pageSelected(current_page - 1);
                
                
                
                
                
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        this.nextPage = function(){
            var current_page = containers.data('current_page');
            if(current_page < numPages()-1) {
                pageSelected(current_page+1);
                
                
                
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        });
        // When all initialisation is done, draw the links
        links = renderer.getLinks(current_page, pageSelected);
        containers.empty();
        links.appendTo(containers);
        // call callback function
        opts.callback(current_page, containers);
    
}

})(jQuery);

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/**
* Callback function that displays the content.
*
* Gets called every time the user clicks on a pagination link.
*
* @param {int}page_index New Page index
* @param {jQuery} jq the container with the pagination links as a jQuery object
*/
function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
var new_content = $('#hiddenresult div.result:eq('+page_index+')').clone();
$('#Searchresult').empty().append(new_content);
return false;
}
/** 
* Callback function for the AJAX content loader.
*/
function initPagination() {
var num_entries = $('#hiddenresult div.result').length;
// Create pagination element
        $("#Pagination").pagination(num_entries, {
        num_edge_entries: 2,
        num_display_entries: 8,
        callback: pageselectCallback,
        items_per_page:1
        });
}

$(window).load(function()            
    { 
    //displays content in a div initially.
    $('#hiddenresult').load('https://ccfxi6qmjdldez0kwgs16w-on.drv.tw/Web/project_UI-views/PrototypZ/JP.html', null, initPagination);
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $("a#target").click(function(e){
    // it gives an error
      ("#hiddenresult").load("https://ccfxi6qmjdldez0kwgs16w-on.drv.tw/Web/project_UI-views/PrototypZ/1stView.html");
      e.preventDefault;
    });
    });
```

Documentation states the above is correct, please make a suggestion as the error I am getting is correct and I am getting the onload function to run just fine, but the one that triggers with a click to an anchor tag is not working, I am getting an error of Uncaught TypeError

> Uncaught TypeError: "#hiddenresult".load is not a function

[https://api.jquery.com/load/](https://api.jquery.com/load)